# Proximity of empty to affect nearby points on faces (Geometry nodes) Blend V 4.0

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, transforms, geometry, empty

I am having a bit of difficulty with the geometry proximity of an empty and having it affect points distributed on a mesh.

When I alter the points offset, the entire set of points move and not only the ones near my Geometry proximity (Empty).
I have no idea how to mix attributes or how to get the bottom *Object Info > Geometry proximity > Map Range* to add any effect to the offset or scaling.

[image]

Comment: See if [this](https://youtu.be/QVucdAh4fjs) YT video helps. It's for Blender 3.4 but probably hasn't changed much since. The Blender 4.0 manual entry is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/sample/geometry_proximity.html#geometry-proximity-node).